# html/css 2 colors in 1 option select list

Tags: html, css, colors, html-select

In my PHP system people can choose a color combination. I'm doing this with a option select list like this:

```
<style>
     OPTION.purple{ width: 100px; background-color: #1d5280; color:white}
     OPTION.green{ width: 100px; background-color: #30843b; color:white}
</style>
<select>
     <option>Choose color</option>
     <option class="purple">Purle/Blue</option>
     <option class="green">Brown/Green</option>
</select>
```

Now each option has 1 color, is it possible to give 1 option 2 colors. So the first half of the option has 1 color, and the other half of the option has another color.

Comment: I don't think you can do that for `option` , you can do something like this for `div` elements though.

Comment: you cant do that without adding a background picture which is 50:50

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With pure CSS without images, I think you can't do it. I recommand you using images.

**[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/QcB94/)**

I use linear gradient in this demo (*note*: change `-webkit-linear-gradient` with `-moz-linear-gradient` if you are using FF or with `-o-linear-gradient` if you are using Opera). It works for `div` element, but it can't be applied to option background (see demo).

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using [**SCSS**](http://sass-lang.com/). Here website teach you all though thing.
--otherwise
if you use different color for diff class means

```
 OPTION.purple{ width: 100px; background-color: #1d5280; color: white;}
 OPTION.green{ width: 100px; background-color: #30843b; color: red;}
```

or u use same color means

```
 OPTION.purple{ width: 100px; background-color: #1d5280;}
 OPTION.green{ width: 100px; background-color: #30843b;}
 option.green, option.purple {color: white;}
```

or

```
<style>
     OPTION.purple{ width: 100px; background-color: #1d5280; }
     OPTION.green{ width: 100px; background-color: #30843b;}
     option.add {color: white}
</style>
<select>
     <option>Choose color</option>
     <option class="purple add">Purle/Blue</option>
     <option class="green add">Brown/Green</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is not what OP wants , he is asking one option two colors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but that's not exactly what I mean. I mean the background-color is 50/50 other colors.